# codeigniter mysqli driver broke session class

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, mysqli

So I have been using mysql driver with codeigniter , but now I need to execute stored procedures and for that Mysqli driver is needed . Because apparently mysql driver doesn't support Stored Procedures. 
Now I can execute Stored Procedures But the native session manager is broken . It can't store session in Ci_session table . gives the following error

Error Number: 2014

Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `last_activity` = 1369672449, `user_data` = 'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"user_id\";s:1:\"1\";}' WHERE `session_id` = '1b29074ae286b900b02e410916d93f26'

Filename: F:\xampp\htdocs\project\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Help!

Comment: It would seem that somewhere in the page, you're doing a (most likely) `SELECT` query against the database without ever reading the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known/common problem with the mysqli driver in Code Igniter. You can overcome it by replacing the `_execute` method in mysqli_driver.php with the below:

```
public function _execute($sql)
{
    // Free result from previous query
    @mysqli_free_result($this->result_id);

    $sql = $this->_prep_query($sql);

    // get a result code of query (), can be used for test is the query ok
    $retval = @mysqli_multi_query($this->conn_id, $sql); 

    // get a first resultset
    $firstResult = @mysqli_store_result($this->conn_id);

    // free other resultsets
    while (@mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id)) {
        $result = @mysqli_store_result($this->conn_id);
        @mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

    // test is the error occur or not 
    if (!$firstResult && !@mysqli_errno($this->conn_id)) {
        return true;
    }

    return $firstResult; 
}
```

Not wanting to change the system files I've taken this a step further and followed the instructions here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers to create my own MY_DB_mysqli_driver in the application/libraries folder and then placed the new `_execute` method into that to override the original in the parent class.